# python write to csv from dictionary while removing list brackets

Tags: python, csv

I have a list of dictionary where the values are lists. I want to write it to a csv file, while removing the [] . But when I run the following code it writes out to csv, but retains the []. How do I write it without that?

```
data_list_of_dx = [{'a_id':['NC01'],'org_id':['FX0'],'status':['Active','Current']}, {'a_id':['bC01'],'org_id':['dr0'],'status':['Dormant','Current']},{'a_id':['NC02'],'org_id':['TX0'],'status':['Active','Late']}, {'a_id':['ty01'],'org_id':['t00r0'],'status':['New','Current']}]
fieldnames = ['a_id','org_id','status']
g_n = 'test_ct_data_2.csv'
g = open( g_n , 'w', encoding = 'utf-8' , newline ='')
writer = csv.DictWriter( g , fieldnames = fieldnames )
writer.writeheader()
for row in data_list_of_dx:
 writer.writerow(row)
g.close()
```

Comment: What is fieldnames?

Comment: updated the code to add the fieldnames part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str.join` on the value in your dict before writing it to the csv.

**Ex:**

```
data_list_of_dx = [{'a_id':['NC01'],'org_id':['FX0'],'status':['Active','Current']}, {'a_id':['bC01'],'org_id':['dr0'],'status':['Dormant','Current']},{'a_id':['NC02'],'org_id':['TX0'],'status':['Active','Late']}, {'a_id':['ty01'],'org_id':['t00r0'],'status':['New','Current']}]
fieldnames = ['a_id','org_id','status']
g_n = 'test_ct_data_2.csv'
g = open( g_n , 'w', encoding = 'utf-8' , newline ='')
writer = csv.DictWriter( g , fieldnames = fieldnames )
writer.writeheader()
for row in data_list_of_dx:
    val = dict((k, ",".join(v)) for k, v in row.items())
    writer.writerow(val)
g.close()
```

- It is better to use `with open()` Ex: `with open( g_n , 'w', encoding = 'utf-8' , newline ='') as g:`

Comment: thanks, that works. I will join using ";" rather than "," though I think. That will prevent it from breaking down when I read the csv file.

Comment: I voted it up, but how do i accept it? Also, why is "with open()" better?

Comment: Reg the `with` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19711344/why-is-with-open-better-for-opening-files-in-python