# Python printing list of items

Tags: python

Below is my function and output. I want to remove the `\n` present in the output.

```
def printInventory():

    fh = open("stock.txt","r")

    print('Current Inventory')
    print('-----------------')

    L=fh.readlines()
    print("List of all Stock Items")
    for i in L:
        L=i.split(",")
    print(L)

    CHOICE = int(input('Enter 98 to continue or 99 to exit: '))
    if CHOICE == 98: 
        menuDisplay() 
    else: 
        exit()
```

Output:

```
List of all Stock Items ['APPLE', '100\n'] ['BANANA', '50\n'] ['CHILLI', '100\n'] ['MANGO', '300\n']
```

I would like to remove the  `\n` from the output

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting rid of \n when using .readlines()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15233340/getting-rid-of-n-when-using-readlines)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`.strip()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) to remove the new line character

For instance:

```
out = ['APPLE', '100\n']
out[1] = out[1].strip('\n')
print(out) # ['APPLE', '100']
```

If you have a list of values, you can just loop through and apply the same logic to each item in the list

Comment: L.strip('\n)  Print(L) ??

Answer (score 0):

Since you are reading each line, you could rewrite the code to iterate over each line once instead of reading them all at once with `readlines()`. This has the benefit of not modifying the list you are iterating over.

```py
def printInventory():
    L = []

    print('Current Inventory')
    print('-----------------')

    with open("stock.txt", "r") as fh:
        for line in fh:
            line = line.strip()
            L.append(line.split(","))
    print(L)
    # ...
```

Using the `with open()` syntax also ensures that the file is closed properly, even if the program crashes: [Why is `with open()` better for opening files in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19711344/why-is-with-open-better-for-opening-files-in-python)